# QDomElement fails to detect right nodeType

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom, qdomdocument

I currenty struggeling to parse XML documents because QDomElement seems to have a problem to detect the correct nodeType.

My xml document has th following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>
    <me>Jani</me>
  </from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The code to read in the document is the following:

```
QFile xmlFile("note.xml");

if (!xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
     qDebug() << "error while opening file";
}

QDomDocument xmlDoc;
if (!xmlDoc.setContent(&xmlFile)) {
    qDebug() << "error while setting xml content";
}

QDomElement rootElement = xmlDoc.documentElement();
QDomElement firstLevel = rootElement.firstChildElement();

while (!firstLevel.isNull()) {
    qDebug() << firstLevel.tagName() << firstLevel.text() << firstLevel.nodeType();
    firstLevel = firstLevel.nextSiblingElement();
}

xmlFile.close();
```

My problem is, that even it only contains text elements, I always receive QDomNode::ElementNode when calling `firstLevel.nodeType()`. But for parsing it is essential to know the correct nodeType. What do I have to do to get the actual type?

Regards,
Frogtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodeType == QDomNode::NodeType` is only set to the innermost node. This is required by the DOM specification:

> The Text interface represents the textual content (termed character
>   data in XML) of an Element or Attr. If there is no markup inside an
>   element's content, the text is contained in a single object
>   implementing the Text interface that is the only child of the element.
>   If there is markup, it is parsed into a list of elements and Text
>   nodes that form the list of children of the element.

To make this clear, look at this slightly modified code:

```
while (!firstLevel.isNull()) {
    qDebug() << firstLevel.tagName() << firstLevel.text() << firstLevel.nodeType();
    QDomNode firstNode = firstLevel.firstChild();
    qDebug() << "And the child has nodetype:" << firstNode.nodeType();
    firstLevel = firstLevel.nextSiblingElement();
}
```