# QDomElement::text() without child element texts?

Tags: qt, qtxml, qdomdocument

I have an xml like:

```
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
  <d>3</d>
</a>
```

and a recursive function that parses `QDomDocument` that wraps it. The function iterates `QDomNode`s, converting them into `QDomElement`s and calls `text()` method to get data.
Unfortunately `QDomElement::text()` works at `<a>` level too and returns: `123`. So it gathers the texts of all nested elements.
I would like it to return an empty string bcs, I would rather not checking `tagName()` value as there are may be plenty of them. So I would rather chek node tag by haveng/not having text inside than vice versa. Is this doable? Is there a method that will return empty string for `<a>` and text values for `<b>, <c>, <d>` levels?
P.S. `QDomNode::nodeValue()` returns an empty text for all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong bcs I was not iterating `QDomNode`s that can't be converted to `QDomElement`s. And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762103/841424):

> This is required by the DOM specification:
>
> ```
> The Text interface represents the textual content (termed character data in XML) of an Element or Attr. If there is no markup
> inside an element's content, the text is contained in a single object
> implementing the Text interface that is the only child of the element.
> If there is markup, it is parsed into a list of elements and Text
> nodes that form the list of children of the element.
> ```

I have no markup inside `<b>`-like elements. So at `<b>` element's level I'm having `el.childNodes().size() == 1`, `el.firstChild().isElement() == false` and `el.firstChild().nodeValue()` returns a non-empty value!